# How to get "type" of a request - web service (ASMX)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services, asmx

I want to log  the "type of" request that access my simple ASMX page. How would I be able to do this?

```
TYPE typeofReq = request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get.GetType();
```

I just want to know how applications are accessing this web service.

Comment: What do you define as the "type" ?

Comment: type is a string. I just want to know how people are accessing this web service.

Comment: You want to know which methods they are calling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know which methods of the web service are being called, implement simple logging that logs that name of the method as part of processing the request.  Alternatively, you should also be able to get this information from the IIS logs.

Comment: I had assumed that you had already added some type of logging capability to your application for exceptions, etc.  If not, check out log4net: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/log4net.aspx